# How can i make order by faster?

Tags: mysql

When i use **ORDER BY** in large table (160000 rows) like this:

```
select HomeTeam,AwayTeam,FTR,FTHG,FTAG,HS,`AS`,`Date`,Elo1A,Elo1B,Elo2A,Elo2B,Elo3A,Elo3B,Elo4A,Elo4B,nElo1A,nElo1B,nElo2A,
        nElo2B,nElo3A,nElo3B,nElo4A,nElo4B from historic
        where (HomeTeam='Crystal Palace' or AwayTeam='Crystal Palace') and datediff('1994-08-20',Date)>0 order by `Date` desc limit 1
```

fetch duration is **1.078 sec / 0.000 sec**

When i use without **ORDER BY** like this:

```
select HomeTeam,AwayTeam,FTR,FTHG,FTAG,HS,`AS`,`Date`,Elo1A,Elo1B,Elo2A,Elo2B,Elo3A,Elo3B,Elo4A,Elo4B,nElo1A,nElo1B,nElo2A,
        nElo2B,nElo3A,nElo3B,nElo4A,nElo4B from historic
        where (HomeTeam='Crystal Palace' or AwayTeam='Crystal Palace') and datediff('1994-08-20',Date)>0 limit 1
```

fetch duration is **0.187 sec / 0.000 sec**

Problem is that without ORDER BY i get wrong result:

> Crystal Palace Tranmere 1993-08-14

but correct is with ORDER BY like this:

> Crystal Palace    Watford 1994-05-08

How can i avoid ORDER BY or somehow smarter call last match from current match?

Comment: As with all sql performance questions... Run an `EXPLAIN` instead of stabbing in the dark.

Comment: If performance is disappointing, try supporting Chelsea.

Comment: Seriously, see normalisation. A database table is not a spreadsheet.

Comment: what is data type of date field and if it is indexed...and how many rows you are getting by your query without limit.

Comment: @ZafarMalik Date is one of the primary keys and data type is Date. 
My table has 4 PK's Div,Date,HomeTeam,AwayTeam and it must be like that because i am getting data from CSV file what doesn't have any ID.
46 rows i get without limit.

Comment: If you are saying that you have a combined PK in order (Div,Date,HomeTeam,AwayTeam) then a seperate index on date column may help you.

Comment: So you suggest me to add index to Date column right?

Comment: yes you can try it....another way can be if you can reduce no of rows fetched by your query...so that mysql is applying reverse ordering on very less rows.

Comment: @ZafarMalik Great, now fetch time is 0.063 :) Thank you.

Comment: its my pleasure...but you need to optimize your table/query as suggested by @Strawberry as it will not use proper index to filter data and as size will grow will create performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

As per our conversation in comments you have created index on date field and getting performance by it-

Further you can try below query which may provide you better performance-

```
SELECT HomeTeam,AwayTeam,FTR,FTHG,FTAG,HS,`AS`,`Date`,Elo1A,Elo1B,Elo2A,Elo2B,Elo3A,Elo3B,Elo4A,Elo4B,nElo1A,nElo1B,nElo2A,
        nElo2B,nElo3A,nElo3B,nElo4A,nElo4B FROM historic
        WHERE (HomeTeam='Crystal Palace' OR AwayTeam='Crystal Palace') and `Date` < '1994-08-20' ORDER BY `Date` DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Note: Here I just remove function from date field so that it can use index to filter data also.